# Copy Textbox Array to Clipboard?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, clipboard

I'm trying to make a simple program, one button generates lottery numbers and the second one copies all the numbers to the clipboard. But no matter how much I google it won't copy anything to clipboard it just crashes, I lost the code that did nothing sadly. Anything help would be lovely, I am a beginner :)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lottery_Number_Generator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private TextBox[] allBoxes;

        private int[] randomArray = new int[7];

        int Min = 1;
        int Max = 60;

        Random rand = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {

        InitializeComponent();

        allBoxes = new TextBox[] { // Creating an array of Textboxes
        boxNum1, boxNum2, boxNum3, boxNum4, boxNum5, boxNum6, boxNum7 };



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            genBtn.Focus();
        }

        private void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TextBox box in allBoxes)
            {
                box.Text = rand.Next(Min, Max).ToString();
            }

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(allBoxes.ToString());
            string boxes = allBoxes[6].ToString();

        }

        private void CopyBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(String.Join("",allBoxes.Select(t=>t.Text)))
```

and also add this at the head of your .cs file:

```
using System.Linq
```

Comment: Gives me an error and the only thing copied to the clipboard is
Clipboard.SetText(String.Join("",allBoxes.Select(t=>t.Text)))

Saying "The method or operation is not implemented"

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I did sadly still the same problem

Comment: I need full information of the exception such as `stack trace` take a screenshot and let me see please.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. `String.Join` needs an array, and linq operations return `IEnumerable`. You need to add `.ToArray()` behind your `Select(...)`. You might also want to use some actual separator, otherwise you get one big number instead of a list of numbers.